# Android - Location Using Play Service API - SettingsClient error in service class

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, android-service, android-workmanager

I have to get the user current location for every 30 min. So i have planned to use Play Service API with Work manager to do this on Background ( Even if my app closed it will get location). Everything working fine if my location is set to ON. I can check whether the location and permissions are available via ***SettingsClient*** option. But the SettingsClient is working only if i use it on Activity. In Workmanager(Service) class while i a trying to use SettingsClient it's showing error like below image

[image]

It require to cast it with Activity

[image]

If i cast it with Activity means no issues while compile time.
[image]

But in run time it giving error like 
[image]

Please give some tips to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for this problem and i thought i can post. May be it will help someone.

I have changed the coding like this

```
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestHighAccuracy)
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequestBalancedPowerAccuracy);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getApplicationContext()).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                try {
                    LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());

                } catch (ApiException exception) {
                    switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                            // user a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                             /*   resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                        OuterClass.this,
                                        REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);*/
                                sendNotification("Failed", "Turn on Location" );
                            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                                // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            sendNotification("Failed", "Setting or not avaible" );

                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**Reference:** https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient